# Plot stacked bar from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe as follows

```
x   score   freq

T   49.0    2000000
T   49.0    2000000
T   49.0    2000000
T   49.0    1824000
T   49.0    856200
F   49.0    800000
F   49.0    746900
F   49.25   4060900
F   49.25   1450000
T   49.25   1000000
T   49.25   1000000
F   49.25   1000000
F   49.5    2748900
F   49.5    2000000
T   49.5    2000000
F   49.5    1834400
```

What I am planning to do here is to sum the rows with same 'x' and 'score' values, then plot a stacked bar with every column representing a unique 'score', with the stacks being 'T' and 'F' for the particular score.

So far, I have grouped them with

```
y = x.groupby(['x','score']).sum()
```

but I do not have enough experience with visualisations to proceed further. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['x', 'score']).sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Comment: You were faster than me, except I believe topic starter wanted to have columns by freq and stacks by x, so correction to your answer:
df.groupby(['score', 'x']).sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

Comment: thanks for the solutions! to further my question, is it possible to show the frequency values in the graph itself, as well as the count?

Comment: I would post question about values as a separate question

Comment: is it possible to swap the axes such that 'score' is on the y-axis?